# Regular Expression for a valid Text

Tags: c#, regex

I was trying to create a regular expression which validate !!

1. If the text has only special character(s), or spaces , It should validate false ...

Ex : @#$##

1. **If it has some text along with special characters at the end, it should return true...**

EX : Test!!

1. If it is starting with a special character apart from space or . It should validate to false.

Ex : @#Test

1. If the special character, except space or coma, comes in between. it should validate to false !!

Ex : te#$ sT

I apologize that, for this complex regular expression, my knowledge do not allow me to put any code which I tried. Because I got nothing apart from `[a-b A-B !@#$%^&*()]`

**UPDATE**

1. Testing with Fischermaen's Answer - ^(\s|\w)\w*\W*$

**sdf SDF!**  : Validate to false

***_*__**  : validate to true (Under scores)

**sadf,sdfsdf** : validate to false

Empty Spaces : Validate to true

Comment: What is, in this case, a special character, or perhaps easier, what is not? It would be good with some examples...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
foundMatch = Regex.IsMatch(subjectString, @"^(?!\W*$)(?=[ .\w]\w*\W*$).*$");
```

I got a headache trying to figure out what you meant. You must learn to express yourself better.

**Explanation:**

```
"
^            # Assert position at the beginning of the string
(?!          # Assert that it is impossible to match the regex below starting at this position (negative lookahead)
   \W        # Match a single character that is a “non-word character”
      *      # Between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
   $         # Assert position at the end of the string (or before the line break at the end of the string, if any)
)
(?=          # Assert that the regex below can be matched, starting at this position (positive lookahead)
   [ .\w]    # Match a single character present in the list below
             # One of the characters “ .”
             # A word character (letters, digits, etc.)
   \w        # Match a single character that is a “word character” (letters, digits, etc.)
      *      # Between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
   \W        # Match a single character that is a “non-word character”
      *      # Between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
   $         # Assert position at the end of the string (or before the line break at the end of the string, if any)
)
.            # Match any single character that is not a line break character
   *         # Between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
$            # Assert position at the end of the string (or before the line break at the end of the string, if any)
"
```

Comment: Got almost correct, and thank you for your great explanation!!

Comment: @Jithu No prob. Accept the answer, or post your own and accept it if it helped you :)

Comment: Sorry I thought I accept the answer, I was in middle of some Jquery Error !! Sorry !! Again I will try explaining questions, better next time :)

Answer (score 1):

Here is my suggestion for you:

```
^(\s|\w)\w*\W*$
```

**Explanation:**

```
^(\s|\w) the first character has to be a whitespace or a alphanumeric (including underscore)

\w*      followed by any number of alphanumeric (including underscore)

\W*$     at the end of the string any number of any *except* alphanumeric characters are allowed.
```

Comment: Thank you Fisch, Let me check :)

Comment: Could be simplified `^\s?\w+\W*\z`. `\z` must be used instead of `$` in this case, because `$` allows a line break to follow it.

Comment: @Qtax: You're right. I didn't mentioned line breaks, because I thought a whole text should be tested.

Comment: Hi Please have a look at the test results, Most of it worked however some of the validated wrongly!!

Comment: @Jithu: Please add the desired results.

Answer (score 1):

As I understand it, you only want to accept strings that have some letters and then some special characters. So something like this:

```
[(a-zA-Z)+(\!\@\#\$\%\^\&\*\(\))+]
```

Comment: Hi thank you, for your time howevr it did not match up to my exact requirement!!

Comment: I see now! I really did miss the mark. Something like this is more appropriate: [(\s|\.)?(a-zA-Z)+((\s|,)(a-zA-Z)+)?(\!\@\#\$\%\^\&\*\(\))+]